# Function works only when section is displayed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I did a number counter but the section that has this counter it's only at the end of my website. So when I get to the section the counting already happened.I want that this function starts working only when I arrive at the section. How can I make this with javascript or jquery?

```js
function animate(obj, initVal, lastVal, duration) {
  let startTime = null;
  let currentTime = Date.now();
  const step = (currentTime) => {
    if (!startTime) {
      startTime = currentTime;
    }

    const progress = Math.min((currentTime - startTime) / duration, 1);
    obj.innerHTML = Math.floor(progress * (lastVal - initVal) + initVal);
    if (progress < 1) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
  };
  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

let text1 = document.getElementById('0101');
let text2 = document.getElementById('0102');
let text3 = document.getElementById('0103');

const load = () => {

  animate(text1, 0, 100, 3000);
  animate(text2, 0, 300, 3000);
  animate(text3, 0, 100, 3000);

}
```

```css
.bloco {
  height: 100em;
}

.container {
  background-color: green;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<body onload="load()">
  <div class="bloco"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <p id='0101'>0</p>
        <p>Visitas</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p id='0102'>0</p>
        <p>Membros</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p><span id='0103'>100</span>%</p>
        <p>Satisfação</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js-anim.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "When I get to this section"? The `onload` function doesn't run until everything has been loaded.

Comment: Do you want to wait until the user scrolls to the end? Use a `scroll` event listener that checks whether the div is visible.

Comment: @Barmar Mine starts running when I open the site. There are some content before this counter section, so I want to be able to see all the content and only when I get to the counter section the counting starts

Comment: I just told you what to do. Run the code in a `scroll` event listener that checks if you've scrolled to the end.

Comment: To sense when an element enters the viewport use IntersectionObserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Change these html identifiers. Why are you using numbers?

Answering the question:

```
<body onload="load()" onscroll="usuarioMoveuScroll()">


let container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
function usuarioMoveuScroll() {
    const containerHeight = container.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    if (scrollY >= containerHeight) {
        animate(text1, 0, 100, 3000);
        animate(text2, 0, 300, 3000);
        animate(text3, 0, 100, 3000);
    }
}
```

Basically, this function will calculate the number of pixels from the top of the page to the container. Using this value it will compare to actual scroll vertical height. Every time you scroll down the vertical scroll height increases while the number of pixels to the top decreases. When de first value  become greater than the second this means that de scroll has reached the container, so it will trigger the animation function.

You can also have a control variable:

```
let alreadyTriggered = false;
```

And you would modify the function:

```
function usuarioMoveuScroll(){
    const containerHeight = container.getBoundingClientRect().top;
       if (scrollY >= containerHeight && !alreadyTriggered) {
          animate(text1, 0, 100, 3000);
          animate(text2, 0, 300, 3000);
          animate(text3, 0, 100, 3000);
          alreadyTriggered = true;
       }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why you ask about all-digit ids? I believe they meet the spec https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes:the-id-attribute-2

Comment: @AHaworth html4 don't allow all digit ids, in html5 it is a bad practice because the readability is affected. High level languages were created to make our lives easier. The code need to be readable for humans. Use only numeric digits in ids is a missed opportunity to pass important info about a element of the code.

Comment: Depends on context as to whether a number is meaningful to the reader.